# Query for an exact number of relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to figure out the proper Cypher queries for group chat which I have modeled as follows:

```
(u:user)-[:in_conversation]->(c:conversation)
(c:conversation)-[:has_message]->(m:message)
```

So if 3 users are in a conversation, I'd have 3 users who have the `in_conversation` relationship.

What is the best way to find or create a conversation for a given list of people

For example, I might have a conversation between userA and userB but **also** have a conversation between userA, userB, and userC.

So if I'm looking to grab the userA-userB conversation, I wouldn't want to grab the userA-userB-userC conversation by accident just because it has the proper relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Find a conversation:

```
// Get a list of users (create if no such people)
//
UNWIND ['A','B','C'] AS participantName MERGE (U:User {name: participantName})

// Sorting is necessary for future comparison
//
WITH U ORDER BY ID(U)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT U) as conversationParticipants

// It is enough to check to find all the conversation of one user
// to check the coincidence of at least one
//
OPTIONAL MATCH (U:User)-[:in_conversation]->(C:Conversation) 
    WHERE ID(U) = ID(HEAD(conversationParticipants))  
OPTIONAL MATCH (inU:User)-[:in_conversation]->(C)

    // Sorting is necessary for future comparison
    //
    WITH conversationParticipants, C, inU ORDER BY ID(inU)
    WITH conversationParticipants, C, collect(distinct inU) as tmp

// Take one conversation in which there is a match 
// with the initial user list
//
WITH conversationParticipants, HEAD(FILTER(c in COLLECT({c:C,tmp:tmp}) 
    WHERE  conversationParticipants = c['tmp']) )['c'] as conversation
RETURN conversationParticipants, conversation
```

2) Create a conversation (need [apoc](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#creating-data) to create uuid):

```
UNWIND ['A','B','C'] AS participantName MERGE (U:User {name: participantName})
WITH U ORDER BY ID(U)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT U) as conversationParticipants
OPTIONAL MATCH (U:User)-[:in_conversation]->(C:Conversation) 
    WHERE ID(U) = ID(HEAD(conversationParticipants))  
OPTIONAL MATCH (inU:User)-[:in_conversation]->(C)
    WITH conversationParticipants, C, inU ORDER BY ID(inU)
    WITH conversationParticipants, C, collect(distinct inU) as tmp
WITH conversationParticipants, HEAD(FILTER(c in COLLECT({c:C,tmp:tmp}) 
    WHERE  conversationParticipants = c['tmp']) )['c'] as conversation

// Use apoc.create.uuid to generate UUID
//
CALL apoc.create.uuid() YIELD uuid as tmpUUID

// Check if conversation not exist
//
WITH conversationParticipants, conversation.uuid as ifexist, 
     COALESCE( conversation.uuid, tmpUUID ) as uuid
MERGE (C:Conversation {uuid: uuid})

// Create :in_converstation relationship
//
FOREACH (x IN CASE ifexist WHEN NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
  FOREACH (user IN conversationParticipants |
    MERGE (user)-[:in_conversation]->(C)
  )
)
RETURN conversationParticipants, C as conversation
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of approaches to do that. I'd suggest to match all the conversations where `userA` and `userB` are involved and make sure that these conversations have exactly two `in_conversation` relationships (namely to A and B). Then you're sure no other person is involved:

```
MATCH (:user{name:'UserA'})-[:in_conversation]->(c:conversation)<-[:in_conversation]-(:user{name:'UserB'})
WITH c, size( (c)<-[:in_conversation]-() ) as count
WHERE count = 2
RETURN c
```